# Android ActionBar with tabs, getting multiple fragment related error messages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I'm getting these errors,

```
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type DataEdit

The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type DataEdit

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type DataEdit
```

for the following code:

```
    public class DataEdit extends Fragment {
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteDatabase d;
Cursor queryAll;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.dataedit); 
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext(),"adfg", null);        
    db=msdb.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSpecies)).requestFocus();
}}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for patience and wisdom.

Here is revised code...

```
    public class DataEdit extends Fragment {
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteDatabase d;
Cursor queryAll;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dataedit, container, false);
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(view.getApplicationContext(),"adfg", null);        
    db=msdb.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edSpecies)).requestFocus();
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragments` behave differently from  `Activities`. The view hierarchy in a fragment is created in `onCreateView` which has to be overridden and returns the `View` object. `findByViewId()` is then called on the inflated view itself. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

In `onCreateView()` you inflate your view like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // your layout
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dataedit, container, false);

    // find the element in the inflated view
    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edSpecies)).requestFocus();

    // get the context from the holding activity
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"adfg", null);
    ...

    return view;

}
```

Comment: you cannot have the exact same error messages, since for example there is no more `setContentView`

Comment: My mistake: new error messages posted above in comment. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: no problem, but I can't find the new error messages

Comment: 1.)  Multiple markers at this line
 - ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type
 - LayoutInflater cannot be resolved to a 
  type

2.)  Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:DataEdit [line: 22] - onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, 
  Bundle)
 - The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type DataEdit

3.)  Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:DataEdit [line: 24] - onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, 
  Bundle)
 - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type DataEdit

Comment: ad 1) Are you sure you are extending the right Fragment class? Either `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (or v7, v13)      ad 2 and 3) If you still get this error, you didn't use the code I provided you

Comment: errors round #2, see amended code above. Thanks.

1.) Multiple markers at this line
 - LayoutInflater cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type

2.) Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:DataEdit [line: 20] - onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, 
  Bundle)
 - The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type View

Comment: ad 1) add an import statement with `import android.view.*;` ad 2) Look exactly at the answer: you need `getActivity().getApplicationContext` and not `view.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Very nice. That nailed it. Thank you for your time. Enjoy the rest of your week.